# time difference between two machines makes problem in service broker communication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, time, service-broker

I have two machines and each machine has a sql instance.between these machines i run service broker ,but one of my machine has a different time from another i mean the machine time of A is `9:00` o'clock and another one is `11:00` o'clock .so the difference between two times makes the message can't be received from another machine , so when i sync both times with the same time the messages are received .

```
so my question is how can i configured the service broker to skip the time difference.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The requirements of security protocols dictate a limit on the time skew between machines.

Use time zones to set your machines to `9:00` vs. `11:00`.